# Java classifying list into multiple lists as per boolean conditions

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list in Java 8 and have certain filtering functions which return boolean result if an item of the list satisfies conditions of that function. I want to split the list into several lists based on the conditions. Currently my code looks like -

```
public void classifyItems(List<SomeType> mylist) {
    //declare and initialize list1, list2, list3
    //these lists will store items as per filtering conditions

    mylist.forEach(item -> {
        if (filteringFunction1(item) {
            list1.add(item);
        }
        else if (filteringFunction2(item) {
            list2.add(item);
        }
        else if (filteringFunction3(item) {
            list3.add(item)
        }
    });

    //other operations on filtered lists
}
```

Is there a cleaner/better way to write the above logic in in Java 8 with streams or some other constructs? I am not very happy with the long if-else ladder. I need separate lists for items satisfying separate conditions.

Comment: there isn't such a thing in the Stream API to partition/group By *multiple* functions at the same time, seems like what you have in place is the best you can get

Comment: What happens to items that do not match a filtering function? Should they be ignored / discarded?

Answer (score 2):

Accepting a list of predicates (or using a *varargs* method) would allow a scalable solution like

```
public void classifyItems(List<SomeType> mylist, List<Predicate<SomeType>> filterFuncs) {
    int ffSize = filterFuncs.size();
    Map<Integer,List<SomeType>> classified = mylist.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item ->
                IntStream.range(0, ffSize)
                         .filter(ix -> filterFuncs.get(ix).test(item))
                         .findFirst().orElse(ffSize)));

    //other operations on filtered lists
}
```

The map keys correspond to the predicate positions in the `filterFuncs` list, so `classified.get(0)` gets you “`list1`”, `classified.get(1)` gets you “`list2`”, and so on and `classified.get(ffSize)` will get you the list of all items not matching any predicate.

It retains the logic of your original code that matching a predicate earlier in the list has precedence over subsequent predicates.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is actually nicely readable, and I don't think it can be improved much, but you can look into using the `groupingBy` collector:

```
Map<String, List<SomeType>> grouped =  mylist.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(it -> {
        if (filteringFunction1(item))
            return "CASE 1";

        if (filteringFunction2(item))
            return "CASE 2";

        if (filteringFunction3(item))
            return "CASE 3";

        return "DEFAULT";
    }));
```

This provides you with a `Map` of `List` instances, where the key is the case each value was categorized as.

Your program likely contains a better candidate for the map's key than a string containing the case name, perhaps an `enum` like in OldCurmudgeon's answer?

Answer (score 0):

For ease of use you can use a basic stream with a filter. This is easy to understand and keeps the code size down but does have a downside of iterating the list 3 times.

```
public void classifyItems(List<String> mylist) {
    List<String> filter1 = mylist.stream().filter(i -> filteringFunction1(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> filter2 = mylist.stream().filter(i -> filteringFunction2(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<String> filter3 = mylist.stream().filter(i -> filteringFunction3(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: yes it would have a drawback of iterating the list three times.

Comment: Provided the size of your list is not significant - you are better accepting the minor performance impact for smaller code size and readability.

Answer (score 0):

When using streams you should try to find a balance between using the stream and coding the logic. I would probably do it something like this.

```
enum Types {
    Type1(list1) {
        @Override
        boolean filter(SomeType it) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    Type2(list2) {
        @Override
        boolean filter(SomeType it) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    Type3(list3) {
        @Override
        boolean filter(SomeType it) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    final List<SomeType> theList;
    Types(List<SomeType> theList) {
        this.theList = theList;
    }

    List<SomeType> getList() {
        return theList;
    }

    abstract boolean filter (SomeType it);
}

public void classifyItems(List<SomeType> mylist) {
    mylist.stream().forEach(
            // walk all types.
            i -> Arrays.stream(Types.values())
                    // Choose only applicable types.
                    .filter(t -> t.filter(i))
                    // Add it to the list.
                    .forEach(t -> t.getList().add(i))
    );
}
```

This encodes the properties of the lists of `SomeType` by providing a `filter` to detect whether this `SomeType` is applicable and the `list` it is related to.

I then use the `stream` only for what it is intended, walking streams and doing stuff with each element.

Comment: that's one more level of indirection; but the problem still remains